# I using function "ofstream" wrong

Tags: c++11

I want write some code to write to a file but I don't know how.  This is the code I have.

```
string filename;
ofstring fout(filename);
```

Why is this code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ofstream fout;
string filename;
fout.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: C++11 added a new `ofstream` constructor taking an `std::string`.  See [basic_ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).  I would guess the original poster is not compiling with the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just misspelled the name of the class.

```
#include <fstream>

std::string filename = ...
std::ofstream fout(filename);
```